# Error: Ionic framework android platform

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and facing issue in adding android platform.
when i run this command

> ionic platform add android

i get error

> command failed with code ENOENT

I've spend whole my day for solving this problem but failed..
i've set set all enviromental variables but still getting this error :(

Pleased suggest any solution to this

Comment: do `npm update -g cordova` then try again, also you have android sdk installed right?

Comment: yeah i've installed android sdk

Comment: did'nt work your solution

Comment: please paste the full error not just that line

Comment: Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
Adding android project...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Awais\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1072:12)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: are you running the command prompt as a admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution. **C:Windows\System32** was missing in Path variable